# ArchTaskExecutor$1 is defined multiple times

Tags: android

When I try to run the project, I am getting this error. Below is my gradle file.
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Type androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor$1 is defined multiple times

build.gradle

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            pseudoLocalesEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            pseudoLocalesEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable "ResourceType"
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.10.0'
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'retrofit', version: '2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.zhihu.android:matisse:0.5.3-beta3'
    implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android:gpuimage:2.0.4'
    
//    implementation group: 'org.opencv', name: 'opencv-android', version: '4.0.1'
//    implementation 'com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:4.0.1'
//    implementation group: 'com.quickbirdstudios', name: 'opencv', version: '4.1.0'


    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.tom-roush:pdfbox-android:2.0.8.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation group: 'com.miguelcatalan', name: 'materialsearchview', version: '1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.johnpersano:supertoasts:2.0'
    implementation 'com.eyalbira.loadingdots:loading-dots:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricalib:3.13.1'
    implementation group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.10.6'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
    implementation group: 'com.andkulikov', name: 'transitionseverywhere', version: '1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    implementation 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'
    implementation group: 'com.nex3z', name: 'flow-layout', version: '1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:pdf-view-pager:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.15'
    implementation project(path: ':sticker')
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1'

    implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxandroid', version: '2.1.1'

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    // Add the SDK for Firebase Cloud Messaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'

    // Declare the dependency for the Performance Monitoring library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'


    implementation project(":AdMaster_Only_Google_V2")
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0'
    implementation project(':nativetemplates')
    //offline text extractor
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:19.0.0'
    //image cropper and picker
    implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.7.2'

    //AppOpen Ads

    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

    implementation 'com.munon:turboimageview:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.13.0'
}
```

I am targeting android 33. Any help is much appreciated as Google wants to update all apps to 33 by 31st of Aug 23.